# which version of laravel Polymorphic Relations to use?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

i want your help ,,, on that in short ( **Video , Post , User**) i want to use these three models to do the following :

**make the user (favorite or comment) on either (video or post)**
what is proper for this situation (**normal Polymorphic or many -to -many Polymorphic** )

any suggestion for that please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a normal Polymorphic for both.

The idea here is that a User can favorite a `Post` or a `Video` -- however, those favorite **actions** are unique to the respective `Post` or `Video`. You couldn't favorite two separate objects in one action - there would be two unique favorites (one for the first object and one for the second object).

The same applies for the comments. You could comment on multiple objects, but each comment would be unique for that object.

The use-case for a many-to-many polymorphic relationship is easiest explained with the concept of **tagging** an object.

You could `Tag` an object with something like "PHP" - You could also `Tag` another object with "PHP".  So, the `Tag` has a many-to-many relationship and can be tagged to multiple separate Models. This is what makes it polymorphic.

So, because a `Favorite` and a `Comment` are only ever tied to one instance of an object -- then that is a normal polymorphic relationship.